# Spark Scala groupBy and merge

Tags: scala, apache-spark, group-by, databricks

I have the following Spark DataFrame that I am manipulating on a databricks notebook, 
let's call the dataframe `df`:

```
src tgt
1   2
1   3
1   4
2   1
2   3
2   5
3   4
4   2
4   5
4   6
5   2
```

I need to take the data and count the number of outgoing edges from src to 
target and from target to src. As follows.

```
node    out_deg in-deg  total_deg
1       3       1       4
2       3       3       6
3       1       2       3
4       3       2       5
5       1       2       3
6       0       1       1
```

For example: node 4 has 3 edges going out (to 2, 5, and 6) and 2 edges coming in (from 1 and 3).
It's total edges = in + out = 3 + 2 = 5.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform a `fullouter` join on the result of group by `src` and `tgt` separately:

```
df.groupBy("src").count().as("srcs")
  .join(df.groupBy("tgt").count().as("tgts"), $"src" === $"tgt", "fullouter")
  .select(
    coalesce($"src", $"tgt") as "node",
    coalesce($"srcs.count", lit(0)) as "out_deg",
    coalesce($"tgts.count", lit(0)) as "in_deg"
  ).withColumn("total_deg", $"in_deg" + $"out_deg")
  .orderBy($"node")
  .show()

// +----+-------+------+---------+
// |node|out_deg|in_deg|total_deg|
// +----+-------+------+---------+
// |   1|      3|     1|        4|
// |   2|      3|     3|        6|
// |   3|      1|     2|        3|
// |   4|      3|     2|        5|
// |   5|      1|     2|        3|
// |   6|      0|     1|        1|
// +----+-------+------+---------+
```

BUT: there might be more efficient solutions, and I'd also recommend looking into [Spark GraphX](https://spark.apache.org/graphx/) which probably has some built-in tools for that.

Comment: @Tzach_Zohar Thank you!